# SQL Server : using a LEN or variable in where clause that contains a join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have created a map table to find various unique strings within a large list of unique hostnames.

The initial code works if I enter the various lengths i.e. `varchar(2)`, `varchar(11)`, etc. It's trying to reference the variable lengths is where my issues began.

I have tried several different combinations before attempting to use a variable.

For example in the where clause, substituting the `varchar(2)` with the `m.[HostNameAlias_IDLength]`

I am also having difficulty using variables.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

TM

P.S. A listing of the code and sample tables are listed below.

Table1

- `HostNameAlias_id` (pk, varchar(5), not null)
- `ProjectName_ID` (int, not null)
- `HostnameAlias_IDLength` (computed, int, null)

Data

```
HostNameAlias_ID    ProjectName_ID  HostNameAlias_IDLength
----------------------------------------------------------
H123456789023456            16009   16
B123456789023               16005   13
C1234567890                 16009   11
d12345678                   16009   9
e123456                     16009   8
f12345                      16003   6
g1234                       16035   5
h123                        16035   4
j12                         16005   3
k1                          16007   2
```

Table2

- [`host name`] (pk, nvarchar(50), not null
- `Projectname_id` (int, not null)

Sample data:

```
Host name          Title           projectname_ID
--------------------------------------------------
C1234567890a1      vp                  16009
C1234567890a2      avp                 16009
h12335             student             16009
h12356             teacher             16009
h12357             prof                16009
```

Query

```
DECLARE @len = INT()
DECLARE @slen = VARCHAR(2);

SELECT DISTINCT
    @len = m.[HostNameAlias_IDLength],
    @slen = CONVERT(varchar(2), m.[HostNameAlias_ID]),
    c.[Host Name],
    m.[projectname_id]
FROM 
    [table1] c
JOIN 
    [table2] m ON c.[projectname_id] = m.[projectname_id]
WHERE 
    CONVERT(varchar(2), [Host Name]) IN (SELECT [HostNameAlias_ID] 
                                         FROM [table2])
```

Comment: Why are you concerned about the length of a varchar? it is of variable length... not seeing the point of this complexity. If you persist in this I think you will need dynamic sql to substitute a length into the varchar conversion.

Answer (score 1):

The length of a result cannot be known in the where clause used to discover that length, so I fail to see why you are attempting this. In addition the column [Host Name] is a varchar(16) so you could encounter up to 16 characters, so just use that maximum ... if the conversion is needed at all.

Below I have just used LIKE instead of IN, perhaps that will assist.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/580c8/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([HostNameAlias_ID] varchar(16), [ProjectName_ID] int, [HostNameAlias_IDLength] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([HostNameAlias_ID], [ProjectName_ID], [HostNameAlias_IDLength])
VALUES
    ('H123456789023456', 16009, 16),
    ('B123456789023', 16005, 13),
    ('C1234567890', 16009, 11),
    ('d12345678', 16009, 9),
    ('e123456', 16009, 8),
    ('f12345', 16003, 6),
    ('g1234', 16035, 5),
    ('h123', 16035, 4),
    ('j12', 16005, 3),
    ('k1', 16007, 2)
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([HostName] varchar(13), [Title] varchar(7), [projectname_ID] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([HostName], [Title], [projectname_ID])
VALUES
    ('C1234567890a1', 'vp', 16009),
    ('C1234567890a2', 'avp', 16009),
    ('h12335', 'student', 16009),
    ('h12356', 'teacher', 16009),
    ('h12357', 'prof', 16009)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
      m.[HostName]
    , c.[HostNameAlias_ID]
    , m.[projectname_id]
    , c.[HostNameAlias_IDLength]
FROM [table1] c
JOIN [table2] m ON c.[projectname_id] = m.[projectname_id]
WHERE [HostName] LIKE ([HostNameAlias_ID] + '%')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/580c8/1/0)**:

```
|      HostName | HostNameAlias_ID | projectname_id | HostNameAlias_IDLength |
|---------------|------------------|----------------|------------------------|
| C1234567890a1 |      C1234567890 |          16009 |                     11 |
| C1234567890a2 |      C1234567890 |          16009 |                     11 |
```

re: `[Host name]` including spaces in column names is a complication that can and should be avoided, so I have used `[HostName]` instead.